# Are the explanations for Mass Effect technology realistically plausible?

Tags: video-games, technology, mass-effect, metamaterials

In the popular video game Mass Effect on Xbox, you can find explanations about the technology that is used in the game. It seems that some of the technology is based on things that could be realized in real life and some that seem questionable.

For example in Mass Effect 2, you can have a cloaking suit, which I see can be realized with a combination of different meta materials in real life. Mass effect particles are something that are clearly made up, but could these be gravitons interacting with other particles or something?

My question is, how much of it is based on real physics that could one day come true, and how much of it is based on just made up stuff with techno-lingo?

Comment: “meta materials” is firmly techno-lingo. Gravitons interacting something is a well-known phenomenon (gravity). Could you describe the cloaking suit and what the “mass effect particles” are supposed to be doing, for the benefit of people who don't know that universe?

Comment: A metamaterial is specifically tailored to cloaking a specific frequency of the EM spectrum. Through the combinations of different metamaterials, you can effectively cloak an entire spectrum of light.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamaterial

The cloaking suit is explained in this wiki article.
http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Tactical_Cloak

The mass effect particles are suppose to do this, explained in this wiki article. They come from these things called Element zero.
http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Element_zero

Comment: You may want to list items you're specifically interested in.  The Mass Effect Codex has *extensive* information on all sorts of technology, planets, species, etc.  Unless you're looking for a 20 page answer, you'd be better served by running down a list of some items of interest.

Comment: I agree with @Keen.  And keep in mind that much of the technological hurdles are explained away with eezo and mass effect fields, neither of which have any basis in fact AFAIK.

Comment: Mass Effect drives are real, everything else is fake.

Comment: i think the issue is that we can only guess at the legitimacy of the tech in the ME universe based on our current understanding of the world around us. for all we know the future describe in ME and our method of getting there could be 100% accurate and we just presently don't have the knowledge on how to get there

Comment: Xantec is absolutely right. Just look at our own technology. If you went to someone in feudal Europe and told them someday you'd be able to put a small box the size of a horse-brush to your ear and instantly talk to anyone anywhere in the world, they'd have thought you mad! To assume that we have, at this point in history, come to understand the whole of science and nature, and anything we don't understand is impossible would be the HEIGHT of arrogance and naivete. It is not only possible, but certain that as our science continues to grow, things now impossible will become common place.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While many of the technologies are clearly impossible with current technologies, they don't seem to violate any physical laws.

As for the actual writers intentions, in the book Extra Lives by Tom Bissell, he says that the creators of the game have a whole list of technologies and ideas for games and plots which they have only begun to use. The list seems to be made up of classic sci-fi technologies along with their own twists, but doesn't seem limited to just "plausible" tech (although it seems they try to keep it that way to make it more believable).

For a good look at the technologies, there's an [interview with scientists](https://youtu.be/iwj8deuPjNE) discussing how "real" these are.

Comment: Both of these links 301 redirect (to axs.com and pcworld.com, respectively, for me)....and now I see that the answer is from 2011. Sorry for the ping, saw this in "Hot Network Questions" and clicked through.

Comment: @chucksmash I've removed the old broken links and added a clip with Michio Kaku which should approximate the old info.